# Android preferences - How to create a ListPreference NOT as a dialog

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a PreferenceScreen:

```
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Example"
    android:key="options">

    <ListPreference
        android:title="I am an example"
        android:summary="Pick One"
        android:key="val"
        android:entries="@array/optionVals"
        android:entryValues="@array/optionVals" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Pressing this opens a dialog with checkboxes, with my options and works fine. I'd like to just open the list in a new preference page, or just display the list on this page. Either way, just get the values out of the dialog in the simplest way possible. Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no "simple" way to do that, at least in terms of the Android SDK itself. You are welcome to dynamically populate a follow-on `<PreferenceScreen>` with `CheckBoxPreference` elements, I guess, or dynamically add a bunch of `CheckBoxPreference` elements to the current screen. There might be a third-party library that has an implementation of this, but I haven't looked for one.

Comment: Good to know at least, thanks. I guess I'll just loop through and populate checkboxes. It should be relatively simple. Thanks.